# Could XY crystal be a special case of X2YZ crystal?

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography

There are some types of crystals we call them XY type (i.e. NaCl) or X2YZ type?
Could XY type be a special case of X2YZ type by assigning Y=Z?

Comment: Sometimes it can, sometimes it can't. That depends on how different the crystal positions of Y and Z are.

Comment: Could you give me some example about why cannot?